# Android/Eclipse problem

Tags: eclipse, android

When I start a new Android project in Eclipse (Helios), the strings.xml has 2 strings, `app_name` and `hello` (which is normal, of course), but they're not shown in the resources view. They seem blank and on clicking anywhere or typing in either views brings up an error dialog, saying "An error occured.. `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I'm able to add more attributes, but this dialog keeps on coming. And no programs have failed to run yet.

What is really the problem and how can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like recently a lot of people are having this problem. I would fill a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, on both my Windows 7 PC and Ubuntu PC, I was not able to run a simple "Hello World" application, or one of the samples. Each time I tried to run I got the "An error has occured" popup, along with a NullPointer exception in the logs.

Does your nullPointer exception refer to `eclipse.jobs` or something similar? (Sorry don't have access to mine to check exact name right now)

I had the issue on 3.6, so downgraded to 3.5.2, that seemed to solve the nullPointer for me, on both my environments

Since you don't mention your eclipse version, I will assume you are on 3.6. What I would suggest :

1. Backup your source code
2. Remove eclipse
3. Download [3.5.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-352/galileosr2)
4. Install ADT
5. Configure ADT to point to your Android SDK
6. Create new project to verify you can run OK

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Android SDK site ([ADT Plugin page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)) they say that their plugin for Eclipse is only supported for Ganymede(3.5) and Galileo(3.6). If you're trying to use the ADT plugin in Helios your problem could be that you're trying too new of a version of Eclipse.
EDIT:There also seems to be a problem with the plugin in 3.6 right now so you should be using 3.5